# No images shown in Lotus Notes 7 and 6.5

Tags: image, lotus-notes, html-email

Email template images are loading properly in Lotus Notes 8 and 8.5 but not on Lotus Notes 7. It is displaying an empty box with red borders instead.

Comment: What's the image format? From memory old versions of Lotus Notes can't render PNGs.

Comment: I have changed the image format to JPG but im still having the same issue.

Comment: In that case, you'll need to paste some code. Out of interest, why do you need it to work in Lotus Notes 7? It's now ridiculously out of date and, last time I checked, had less than 0.1% market share. So unless you're emailing to a niche sector, it's probably not worth worrying about.

Comment: @Blowski Personally, I'm just trying to figure out why they never show up in my email testing software. Curious, really.

Answer (score 0):

IBM have released some technotes about this

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21110585

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21224772

Comment: Can you give a tl;dr of the links?

Comment: Seconding Blowski. What is a "perweb" process?